# Slow loading time with file_get_contents

Tags: php, sql

I had an issue with the google geocode api daily request limit. So I figured I'd save the location everytime a new item is added to my database and only make a request when a new item is added, this way I will never hit my daily limit.

But I am struggling to make it work.

So I added a column called `requested` this is 0 by default and when a request is made to google I change it to 1.

Using the following code:

```
// Kijk of er al een plaatsnaam en straatnaam in de database bestaan bij het artikel
$existcheck = "DESC snm_content";
$existcheckcon = $conn->query($existcheck);
$existcheck = $existcheckcon->fetch_assoc();

if($existcheck['requested'] == 0){
    $getlatlong = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$bedrijven['plaats'].",".$straatnaam."&key=myapikey");

    $updatetable = "UPDATE snm_content SET requested = 1";
    $updatetablecon = $conn->query($updatetable);

    // echo $updatetable;

}else if(
    $existcheck['requested'] == 1){
}
```

This works, but my site is incredibly slow, as if it is still making the requests. Why could that be?

I posted only a part of my code to make it more clear, I'll post my entire php code below:

```
$bedrijven = "
SELECT
  cnt.id, cnt.title, cnt.introtext, cnt.ordering, cnt.images, cnt.alias, cnt.state, f.item_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 3 THEN f.value END) AS plaats,
  MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 1 THEN f.value END) AS straat
FROM snm_fields_values f
JOIN snm_content cnt
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE cnt.state = 1
GROUP BY f.item_id
ORDER BY f.item_id, plaats, straat";

$bedrijvencon = $conn->query($bedrijven);
$bedrijvenarray = [];

while($bedrijven    = $bedrijvencon->fetch_assoc()){
  $straatnaam = '';
  $plaatsnaam = '';
  // Stop $bedrijven in een array
  array_push($bedrijvenarray, $bedrijven);
  // Vervang de straatnaam spaties met plusjes voor de filegetcontents url
  $straatnaam .= str_replace(' ', '+', $bedrijven['straat']);
  $plaatsnaam .= $bedrijven['plaats'];

  // Kijk of er al een plaatsnaam en straatnaam in de database bestaan bij het artikel
  $existcheck  = "DESC snm_content";
  $existcheckcon = $conn->query($existcheck);
  $existcheck = $existcheckcon->fetch_assoc();

  if($existcheck['requested'] == 0){
      $getlatlong = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$bedrijven['plaats'].",".$straatnaam."&key=myapikey");

      $updatetable = "UPDATE snm_content
      SET requested = 1";
      $updatetablecon = $conn->query($updatetable);

      // echo $updatetable;

  }else if(
      $existcheck['requested'] == 1){
  }

  $latlongarray = json_decode($getlatlong);
  $lat = '';
  $lng = '';


  $bedrijfimage = $bedrijven['images'];
  $bedrijfimg = json_decode($bedrijfimage);

  if($bedrijfimg->image_intro != ''){
     $bedrijvenimage = '../cms/'.$bedrijfimg->image_intro;
  }else{
     $bedrijvenimage = '../images/logo_ovn.png';
  }

  $image_array = array('intro_image'=>''.$bedrijvenimage.'');
  // Leeg de latlong na elke loop
  foreach ($latlongarray->results as $key => $latlong){
    //  $latlonglijst .= $latlong->geometry->location->lat.'&nbsp;';
    //  $latlonglijst .= $latlong->geometry->location->lng.'<br>';
    $lat .= $latlong->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng .= $latlong->geometry->location->lng;
    // array_push($bedrijvenarray, $lat, $lng);
    $new_array = array('lat'=>''.$lat.'', 'lng'=>''.$lng.'');

  }
  // Voeg lat en lng toe aan de $bedrijven array
  $bedrijven['lat'] = $new_array['lat'];
  $bedrijven['lng'] = $new_array['lng'];
  $bedrijven['intro_image'] = $image_array['intro_image'];
  $bedrijvenarray1[] = $bedrijven;
}
$jsonobject = json_encode($bedrijvenarray1);
```

The column requested has changed to `1` for every row, so it should never make the request anymore, still it is really slow and it is because of this code, because when I remove it, it's fast again.

Comment: Maybe the key `requested` doesn't exist in `$existcheck`? In that case the result of `$existcheck['requested'] == 0` would be `true`.

Comment: @mch Yeah it does, I get everything with `$existcheck` and requested is a column inside that table.

Comment: `DESC snm_content` will not return any data, instead it will just describe the fields in that table, without listing any data records. Couldn't you just add `cnt.requested` to the initial SQL query and leave the second query be? Also, you need to add a condition to the update (`update snm_content set requested = 1 where id = {$bedrijven['id']}`), otherwise all records in the table will be updated instead only the current one you are using.